# How to create a incremental variable in a position of list on Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to do a test that lists all of the configuration files in a folder and performs one configuration at a time, but I don't know how to insert an incremental variable at the position of the list. In my code below, only the first file of the first position is loaded. Can anyone help a robot beginner?

````
    ${list} =   List Files in Directory     ${input_folder}  
    ${lista} =  Create List     ${list}
    ${number_files} =   BuiltIn.Get Length    ${list} 

    :FOR    ${i}     IN   ${lista}     
        Run Process        python     aster_scripts/setup_transform.py       --input-yaml   ${input_folder}${lista[0][0]}          
        Generate plan                
    END```
````

Answer (score 2):

For using a list in a list content you need to use @

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
List Files
    @{list}=      List Directory     ${EXECDIR}

    FOR    ${filename}     IN   @{list}
        Log To Console  ${filename}
    END
```

It is also possible to use a list with $. As far as I can see it is not documented but ${list} is some kind of a "reference to list" Perl's style. It is not exactly like that but it helps me understand it. So with ${list} you can pass a list to a keyword as a scalar.